# How to use if condition on a variable in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, variables, if-statement

Hi I am a newbie in MATLAB.

I have a variable named *predictLabels* which has values i.e 1,2,3,4. For each image the value of *predictLabels* changes. In workspace it shows as **predictLabels = '1'** *etc*.

Problem is, when i use if condition to that variable nothing hapens. Partial code given below-

```
if predictLabels == 1
    imshow(img);
end
```

The above code is not working. No error showing, even compiler is not entering in if statement.  I think there is a function for this kind of condition check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `predictLabels` doesn't contain a numeric value. Instead, it appears to be either a [character array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html) (`'1'`) or a [cell array of characters](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-arrays-of-strings.html) (`{'1'}`). I'm guessing it's the latter, which is why it displays as `... = '1'` instead of `... = 1`. Whichever one it is, you should use [`strcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) instead of [`==`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html) in your conditional check:

```
if strcmp(predictLabels, '1')
  imshow(img);
end
```

If you'd like to check the data type of a variable, you can use the [`class`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) function:

```
>> predictLabels = '1';
>> class(predictLabels)

ans =
char
```

Or you can use [`whos`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) to check the data for the whole workspace:

```
>> whos
  Name               Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  predictLabels      1x1                 2  char
```